# Possible to generate html from a partial, then send html as response to ajax call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if I could re-use a partial that generates html.

I have a ajax request that passes text to my controller, and then it responds with some html.

The html it returns is the same html then I generate using a partial on the same view page.

Could I somehow re-use this partial in my controller action that responds to the ajax request?

Comment: If you say what you mean instead of saying "call" in place of the proper verb, your question would make a lot more sense. AJAX *request*. HTTP or controller *response*. *Render* a partial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if it's AJAX request using `request.xhr?` and specify `:layout => false` to render just the partial file with no layout.

```
if request.xhr?
  render :partial => 'partial_name', :layout => false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understood the question differently, but you could do something like this to replace the div where you rendered the partial on the view page with an updated version, using the same template:

show.html.haml

```
.post
  = render :partial => 'post
```

And in show.js.haml (the AJAX response)

```
== $('.post').html('#{escape_javascript(render :partial => 'post')}');
```